# Removal of Node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, algorithm, tree

I have the a BST that looks like this:
I'm trying to remove the node 12 (which has 2 children),
I'm wondering if I'm removing it correctly?

Before Removal

```
          12
        _/   \_
     5          18
  /     \     /     \
 =       =   15     19
 2       9   /  \     
            13   17
```

After removal:

```
          18
        _/   \_
     5          19
  /     \     /    
 =       =   15     
 2       9   /  \     
            13   17
```

Is my implementation correct here?
Thanks.

EDIT UPDATED AFTER REMOVAL:

```
          13
        _/   \_
     5          18
  /     \     /    \
 =       =   15     19
 2       9     \     
                17
```

Comment: What are the properties of a binary search tree? Do they still hold for your new tree? You should be able to answer this question yourself.

Comment: I believe they do, but I'd like confirmation  hence why I'm asking.

Comment: What are the properties of a binary search tree?

Comment: The tree additionally satisfies the binary search tree property, which states that the key in each node must be greater than all keys stored in the left sub-tree, and smaller than all keys in right sub-tree. (The leaves (final nodes) of the tree contain no key and have no structure to distinguish them from one another.

Comment: OK, so is 18 smaller than all the nodes in its right sub-tree?

Comment: It appears to be yes.

Comment: 18 is smaller than 15 or 13 or 17? To delete a node, everything should be laid out in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion). In your particular case you should've promoted 18 up, as you did, and then hook 12 into the leftmost sub-node of 18, which would be 13. So promote 18 and its entire subtrees up without change, then take 12 and make it the left child-node of 13.

Comment: But im deleting the node 12?

Comment: Sorry, make left sub-tree of 12 the left sub-tree of 13, so that would be the 5 then.

Comment: I've updated it, is this correct now?

Comment: The tree is correct but I don't understand how the single deletion of the 12-node would end up with that tree. Anyway, I've left an answer with the steps you should take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a simple example.

Consider this tree:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

To delete A, do the following:

1. Pick either B or C as its replacement, you promote this node up to take the place of A.
2. Take the other subnode (B or C) and hook it into the first (B or C)

   - If you picked B as the replacement for A, you need to hook C into B as its new leftmost subnode
   - If you picked C as the replacement for A, you need to hook B into C as its new rightmost subnode

By "left/rightmost subnode" I mean that you need to navigate downwards in the left or right direction as long as you have subnodes in that direction, then when you come to a node with no left/right subnode (according to which direction you're going), hook the "other node" into it as its new subnode in that direction.

Let's consider picking B first, you would end up with this:

```
   B
    \
     ...
        \
         C
```

If you pick C first, you would end up with this:

```
      C
     /
  ...
 /
B
```

So back to your tree, which started out as this:

```
        12
      /    \
     5      18
    / \    /  \
   2   9  15   19
         /  \
        13   17
```

To delete 12, and you picked 18 to replace it, you first promote 18:

```
     5      18
    / \    /  \
   2   9  15   19
         /  \
        13   17
```

Then, since 18 corresponds to C in my previous example, you will need to hook 5 into 18 as its leftmost subtree, giving you this final tree:

```
        18
       /  \
      15   19
     /  \
    13   17
   /
  5
 / \
2   9
```

Let's look at what would've happened if we picked 5 to replace 12 instead:

promote 5:

```
     5      18
    / \    /  \
   2   9  15   19
         /  \
        13   17
```

Then hook 18 into 5 as its new rightmost subtree:

```
    5
   / \
  2   9
       \
        18
       /  \
      15   19
     /  \
    13   17
```

Either would be fine. There's probably some more information on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion) that would be worthwhile reading.

Comment: Hmm the way I'm ending up with the tree is, I look in the right subtree of 12, and find the value just greater than 12, so 13. Then 12 becomes 13, and now I have a node 13 with no children (at the bottom) so I can remove the duplicate by itself, thus I get this tree.

Comment: What if 13 had a right child? Regardless of your approach, you should write unit-tests for your tree code. Come up with lots of tree examples and which nodes to delete and write code to verify the integrity of the tree afterwards. Without hardcoding the exact approach into the unit-test you could write a standardised way of testing that would create a list with all the values in-order, and verify that the list is still sorted, and that it is only missing the value in the node you deleted.

Comment: Then I would apply the case of a node having one child, so remove the duplicate 13 at the bottom, and point 13's parent to the right child?